# Calculate sum of numbers found by a grep-like regex using only Perl

Tags: perl

I would like simplify this command by using only Perl, now it works fine but it's pretty long and spams logs

```
perl -lane '$t+=$_ for @F; print $t' <<<$(ipset list -t | grep "Number of entries" | tr -d '\n')
```

Basically it needs to sum the numbers found by a grep pattern who searches for specific fields in the output of that command

Thanks

```
ipset list -t
Name: xxxxxxxxxx
Type: hash:net
Revision: 7
Header: family inet hashsize 1048576 maxelem 1000000 bucketsize 12 initval 0xe63ffc5b
Size in memory: 1373520
References: 1
Number of entries: 28468

Name: xxxxxxxx
Type: hash:net
Revision: 7
Header: family inet6 hashsize 1048576 maxelem 1000000 bucketsize 12 initval 0x6d8601a2
Size in memory: 8444896
References: 1
Number of entries: 123695
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed a sample of the input generated by ipset.

Comment: Added it in main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -lwe '/Number of entries: (\d+)/ and $s += $1 for `ipset list -t`;
           print $s || 0'
```

- `-l` adds newlines to `print`. If your Perl is recent enough, you can use `-E` and [say](https://perldoc.pl/say) instead of [print](https://perldoc.pl/print).
- Calling backticks in list mode (which `for` enforces) returns individual lines. Each line is matched against the regex and the number is extracted. When there's a match, the extracted number is added to `$s`. The sum is printed at the very end (or zero if there's nothing to sum).

Comment: This works, thank you. Just for the sake of it how do i replace "print" with "say" and -E? I tried to do it directly and it got some various errors

Comment: perl -lwE instead of perl  -lwe and say $s instead of print $s.

Comment: Not impressed by the use of backticks here. Also, doesn't handle an empty output from `ipset` well. Alternative: `ipset list -t | perl -nle '/Number of entries: (\d+)/ and $s += $1; END { print $s // 0 }'`.

Comment: @Aditya There is no need for `say` when using `-l` and print. `-l` handles line endings and will add newline to print. `-E` on the other hand enables ALL optional features, and is overkill if all you want is to add a line ending. If you have already enabled `-l`, there is literally no point in enabling `-E` for `say`.

Comment: @ikegami: Updated to handle empty output. I used backquotes because that's how I understood "using only Perl".